# Зачем нужны поля класса в js?

Tags: javascript

Разбираюсь с классами в js и возник вопрос. Когда мы создаем объект класса, вызывается конструктор класса и происходит инициализация свойств объекта. Но зачем нам тогда возможность создавать свойства класса вне конструктора? Создать свойство одинаковое для всех объектов класса или есть еще назначения?

```
class someClass {
  prop1 = 'value';
  prop2;
  constructor(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Вот к примеру в классе сверху, зачем создавать prop1, prop2 и т.д. если свойства определяются в конструкторе?

Comment: Это точно такие же свойства, просто их указание не требуется в конструкторе. Могут использоваться для заданий значений свойств по умолчанию.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko т.е. если бы я в конструкторе написал                
`constructor(prop1,prop2) {this.prop1 = prop1, this.prop2 = prop2}`, то, получается, я обращаюсь к тем же свойствам, что я объявил до конструктора?`

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор необходим для свойств, требующих инициализации свойствами, переданными при создании объекта. Если классу не требуется такая инициализация, то можно обойтись без конструктора:

```
class Blog {
  author = "Aleksandr";
}
```